# Compiler disagreement on three way comparison of bitfield member

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I came across this curious error emitted by Clang 16:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <compare>

struct Foo {
    std::uint64_t A;
    std::uint64_t B: 32;
    std::uint64_t C: 33;
};

int main() {
    Foo a{}, b{};
    a.A <=> b.A;
    a.B <=> b.B;
    a.C <=> b.C;
}
```

Clang refuses to compile this program with the error message

> argument to 'operator<=>' cannot be narrowed from type 'std::uint64_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'unsigned int'

on the line `a.B <=> b.B;`, where the 32-bit bitfield member is compared. The non-bitfield and the 33-bit bitfield members don't cause any errors.

GCC 13.2 emits a similar message, but only as a warning, MSVC 19 compiles it without complaints.

It seems to me that at least Clang and GCC select an overload of `operator<=>` that takes `unsigned int` parameters, even though the argument type should be `std::uint64_t`, as far as I can tell. None of the compilers have similar errors for the other comparison operators.

What is going on here and which compiler is correct?

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/938aW7Pvs)

Comment: [CWG2627](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2627.html)?

Comment: Because you seem confused by the overload choice: Integral promotions promote bit-field prvalues to `int` or `unsigned int` if these can hold the bit-field width, regardless of the bit-field type, even if the bit-field type has higher integer rank. It is then however inconsistent that these are considered narrowing conversions as per link above and answer already given.

Comment: In the above I should have said "can hold the bit-field values", not just "width": So in your case, taking into account signedness, if the width is <= 31 you get `decltype(a.B + b.B) == int`, for width 32 you get `decltype(a.B + b.B) == unsigned int` and for width larger 32 you get `decltype(a.B + b.B) == uint64_t`. And `<=>` overloads are chosen analogously. Only in the first two cases is there potentially a narrowing conversion going by the expression types alone.

Comment: @user17732522 Thanks, this makes sense, I did not know this rule applies here. But how come the behaviour is different for the other comparison operators?

Comment: @chrysante As I described above, integral promotion does not change the types in these cases, so there is no conversion that could be narrowing to being with.

Comment: bitfields are implementation defined.  So it is not too strange behavior will differ

Comment: @user17732522 Wait, where did you describe that? I'm confused. Why does integral promotion change the type in `a <=> b` but not in `a < b`?

Comment: @chrysante The same promotion rule applies to `<` as well and it is still a narrowing conversion before the CWG issue resolution. However `<=>` has a specific rule that forbids narrowing conversions, while other operators do not have that.

Comment: @user17732522 Okay I got it. I get that they want to get rid of implicit narrowing conversions but it's kind of strange that `operator<` and `operator<=>` differ in behaviour in that regard.

Comment: @chrysante I haven't looked in the relevant papers for a rationale, but I suppose they wanted to make the usage a bit safer. It would be better if implicit narrowing conversions were forbidden for all operators, but that can't be changed for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For C++20 as shipped, Clang is the most correct. You are invoking a narrowing conversion, which is not allowed in this context. This is because bitfields are not considered when deciding what is a narrowing conversion. Per [[dcl.init.list]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init.list#7), the only thing that matters for narrowing is the source type; there is no special language for variables that are bitfields.

This was filed as a defect in the standard as [CWG 2627](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2627.html), which was adopted. [[dcl.init.list]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.list#7.4.1) for the forthcoming C++23 now has wording for bitfields:

> the source is a bit-field whose width w is less than that of its type (or, for an enumeration type, its underlying type) and the target type can represent all the values of a hypothetical extended integer type with width w and with the same signedness as the original type or

As this was filed as a defect against C++20, C++20 compilers are expected to adopt the new behavior as well. So technically, MSVC is the most correct compiler.

Comment: Thank you! But how come that the same thing does not happen for the other comparison operators?